# Cannot change number of columns and rows in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a grid where you can adjust the number of rows and columns using a slider. I have no syntax errors in my code, however it is not doing what i want it to. The grid and slider have the following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="Neural_Network_Investigation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Neural_Network_Investigation"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="Auto"
    MaxHeight="520" MinHeight="450"
    Width="Auto" 
    MaxWidth="700" MinWidth="630">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.RowSpan="4"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Background="Gray"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="1"
              x:Name="NetworkGrid"
              ShowGridLines="True"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontSize="12"
                           Text="Grid Size: "/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="GridSizeText"
                           FontSize="12" Text=""
                           MinWidth="15"/>
                <Slider x:Name="GridSizeSlider"
                        Minimum="4" Maximum="20"
                        TickPlacement="BottomRight"
                        TickFrequency="1"
                        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                        Width="100"
                        ValueChanged="GridSizeSlider_ValueChanged"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When the slider is changed, I want the number of rows and columns in NetworkGrid to be updated to match:

```
    private void GridSizeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        var GridSize = (int)GridSizeSlider.Value;
        GridSizeText.Text = GridSize.ToString();
        NetworkGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
        NetworkGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();

        double SquareWidth = NetworkGrid.Width / GridSize;
        double SquareHeight = NetworkGrid.Height / GridSize;

        for(int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < GridSize; columnNumber++)
        {
            var column = new ColumnDefinition();
            NetworkGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);

            for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < GridSize; rowNumber++)
            {
                var row = new RowDefinition();
                NetworkGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);

                var square = new Border();
                square.Background = Brushes.Black;
                square.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columnNumber);
                square.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the program, I see nothing despite ShowGridLines being enabled. This means that it is not adding the columns and rows to the grid. How do I fix this?

I have used code from this article: [How to add rows and columns to a WPF Grid programmatically](http://deepak-sharma.net/2013/02/01/how-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-wpf-grid-programmatically/)

I have also checked out [this blog](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) showcasing a class that allows you to draw a Grid with a dynamic number of rows or columns, however i cannot get my head around how to use the class in my own program.

Comment: You're not setting a width for the column so I'm wondering if they are just squishing together?

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me.

Comment: as @WBuck says, i tested it too, and works just fine

Comment: Post all of your xaml.

Comment: @WBuck why can i not see the grid lines?

Comment: Ok I just retried and it works, weird. thanks anyway